# Can I use amazon s3 without cloudfront?

Tags: wordpress, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, digital-ocean, buddypress

I am making a buddypress site hosted on digitalocean, users will be able to upload media files to the site, I wanted to host the files on amazon s3 instead of my server, so here are my questions -

1. Is it a good idea to host the media files on amazon s3 or should I host them on my digitalocean server?
2. From what I understand I need amazon cloudfront to distribute the files from S3. Is this true or can the media files be distributed without the need for cloudfront.
3. If you know a better alternative to this what would you recommend?

And by distribution I mean users will be able to share media files such as images,audio and video and view them as they wish like they would with facebook or instagram.

Answer (score 0):

https://wordpress.org/plugins/amazon-s3-and-cloudfront/

Cloudfront is the content delivery network which will ensure that the visitors gets the media from the closest location

I have used this setup earlier and hosted files on S3.

Answer (score 0):

You can easily use S3 to store limitless number of objects in the bucket, and WordPress images make perfect sense. There are number of plugins for WordPress that enable S3 upload with ease. Configuring CloudFront to distribute images from S3 endpoint is a breeze, but you can easily serve images from S3 (works both http and https) and performance is superior over any DigitalOcean servers. Let me know if you want to hear more and I can explain in detail how you can set it up successfully.